# Work environment and relationship, not saying hi gives the right to get insulted?

Tags: colleagues, work-environment, human-resources

I work as a data analyst and I had a colleague refer the data to us for Analysing. The referral form had the folder Location but there were 8 folders and the form did not say the names of the files. I texted my colleague but their status changed to away so I emailed.

- I said Hi X in both the email and the msg.
- The response came with no Hi at all and directed me to another
  folder.
- I opened the folder and there are many files.
- So, I called to cut the time and I said hi and asked where is the
  data?
- The reply was Which data? I asked them if they sent us a referral
  form, do you know what is the form used for?
- The reply was no, they told me to fill out the form and send it to you.
- I asked, do you know what we are doing here?
- The reply was You are rude. I said I am sorry, what? The reply was
  you are very rude. I asked how am I being rude. The reply was I do
  not like your tone, your tone is very rude. I said okay you call your
  manager and I will call mine, have a good day and I hung up.
- The person told their manager that I did not say hi and started asking
  for the data.
- My manager received the msg and passed it on to me that it is
  perceived as rude and blunt if I start asking for the data without
  saying hi.
- I told my manager that they did not like my tone, my tone was rude
  and they said nothing about not saying hi to them. So I took a screenshot of the conversation and the email where I said hi but they did
  not say hi back. I am in the UK, the person is British and I am not and my accent is not British too.

Does that give them the right to insult people this way just because I did not say hi? So, if people started calling others rude just because they did not say hi to them then that is out of the line.

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe this should be asked at https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Thank you @Berend

Comment: @Berend As this question is specifically about a workplace context and the situation was already escalated to managers it seems perfectly appropriate here. Note that we don't encourage cross-posting of questions unless there are specific aspects that another site would be able to address.

Comment: ... Although with the now deleted comment guessing at racism, and previous question from op, I think general direction at interpersonal is not a miss for OP. Not with this specific case exactly, but to avoid future ones.

Answer (score 4):

Native Brit here (although I now live elsewhere).

If the conversation went exactly how you've written it - yeah, I'd consider it being rude.

The line that jumped out at me was this one:

> do you know what we are doing here?

If someone asked me that, as a native english speaker - here is what it sounds like:

"You are a clueless idiot who doesn't know what's going on"

Now - reading between the lines, I suspect the colleague was under pressure and felt you were nagging them (also rude).

Does that mean how they reacted was right? No. But in the same breath, as you've written the conversation, it would seem rude to me. I wouldn't hang up and get management involved - but that's me, I've got thick skin.

Comment: I like this answer... I think it could be expanded a little. Assuming that the bullet points are the order of the conversation. OP Asked "Do you know what we are doing here?" then SM answered  "You are rude." I think that it is fair to say that those two statements are connected seeing as one followed immediately after the other.

Comment: It is funny that no one read the beginning of the conversation. I did say hi in the text msg, email and on the call. I asked for the folder and then for the file. They had no clue which data I am talking about and why they sent the form to us. Their manager told them to fill the form and send it us without explaining why. So, they do not know why they sent the referal form to us and they do not which data I am looking for. Do I have to ask that obvious question? In my mind yes because I wanted to raise it in our mgt meeting that this is a lack from the managers that we are facing a lot.

Comment: Did I expect that reaction? No, I did not. Because I have been asked this question with the exact word but I did not take it badly the same way they did. My respond was No, please tell me because I am new in the company. I talked with my manager and my senior manager and I said exactly the same, and they could not find another way to phrase the question. Their respond was, they obviously had no clue about what is going on and their reaction is unacceptable. But they lied to their manager about not saying hi so they sided with their team member.

Answer (score 3):

You not saying "Hi" was not the problem... Probably the only part of the chain that SM was able to point to specifically. But not the problem.

Let's look at the most relevent conversation chain...

OP said:

> "Do you know what we are doing here?"
> Depending on how you said this, and the context of the conversation. This statement ranges from moderately rude to very rude.

SM (subject matter) Then replied

> "You are rude"

Based on that conversation chain. SM found "Do you know what we are doing here?" to be rude.

Now where did OP go wrong in this conversation.

### Problem: Not enough detail in OP's emails/ a communication mismatch.

OP asked where the data was located. SM who probably works with this data all of the time, didn't realize that OP didn't know what files the data was located in, and thought that OP just needed to know where the files were located. SM answered this question.

### Fix:

Ask instead "What files did you want analyzed, I looked in folder XYZ but couldn't tell what files I was supposed to look at." (Possibly offer some files that you thought were the data files, not needed.)

Brief but enough information that SM knows what you are talking about... Including the request form would probably help SM know what data OP needs.

### Problem: Made assumptions with the call

OP called out of the blue and didn't introduce themselves or their problem properly.

"Where is the data" is not the best way to start a phone conversation. And is a little rude. As SM doesn't know who you are, or what data you are talking about.

### Fix:

"Hi! this is OP from data analysts r us.." Possibly pause in case they want to say hello back.. " I am having difficulty locating some data you wanted analyzed. Name of the data/location... Do you know what files in folder location needed analysis?"

### TLDR

This is mostly on you. And it is not because English isn't your native tongue. You were unable to explain what it is you wanted from SM in your emails. File names, instead of Folder location... And got frustrated over that. Then called SM while you were frustrated and did not exchange social niceties. And then accused SM of being ignorant and having no clue what was going on.

Of course SM would complain.

Comment: It is funny that no one read the beginning of the conversation. I did say hi in the text msg, email and on the call. I asked for the folder and then for the file. They had no clue which data I am talking about and why they sent the form to us. Their manager told them to fill the form and send it us without explaining why. So, they do not know why they sent the referal form to us and they do not which data I am looking for. Do I have to ask that obvious question? In my mind yes because I wanted to raise it in our mgt meeting that this is a lack from the managers that we are facing a lot.

Comment: Did I expect that reaction? No, I did not. Because I have been asked this question with the exact word but I did not take it badly the same way they did. My respond was No, please tell me because I am new in the company. I talked with my manager and my senior manager and I said exactly the same, and they could not find another way to phrase the question. Their respond was, they obviously had no clue about what is going on and their reaction is unacceptable. But they lied to their manager about not saying hi so they sided with their team member.

Comment: The SM can raise to their manager but not to respond that way. We are not in high school. They could have been honest and said No instead of starting insulting and then lying about it.

Comment: Then their manager responded to my manager when he showed them the screen shots of the text msg and the email, I said Hi and they did not say hi back. Their manager response was they did not do anything wrong and I am the one was rude to them. Just like you, you missed the beginning but got triggered by the last question.

Comment: @Fatima Do you even know why your last question was rude?

Comment: I apologize for my rudeness above. Its purpose is educational..

Comment: My question considered rude because I made them feel stupid, they do not know what is the data, they do not know the purpose of the referal and they do not what we are doing here. Was that my intention Not at all. My intention was to verify if the manager told them the purpose of the referal form to us and why they have to refer the data to us. Was this point raised from my manager to theirs, yes. It is a fail on their part but they are not held accountable for it.

Comment: So, now my question to you, why would they say I did not say hi is the reason for calling me rude, but it is okay for them not to say Hi back?

Comment: @Fatima Email's/Chat have different rules then phone calls.  As can be seen by you/me not saying "HI" and yet neither one of us considered it rude.  The initiator of a conversation is expected to start with something polite. Because you are asking them for something...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146968/discussion-between-questor-and-fatima).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to follow exactly what happened but generally speaking, yes, it can be viewed as rude when you start a conversation with someone and you did not start out with some form of salutation like so...

> Good morning Jean. I was wondering if you had a chance to get that info for me?
>
> Hi Tom. How are you? Are you able to discuss that proposal?

Something like these suggestions. I personally get annoyed when someone that I don't really know or work with pings me on Teams and just starts asking questions, etc. and doesn't bother to introduce themselves, say hi, etc.

As for their accusation that you are rude, I can guess by your question that you may be a little terse when speaking to people due to English not being your primary language (assumed). Also asking someone "Do you know what we do here?" can be construed as aggressive and confrontational so you may want to tone if down a bit.

With all of this being said, no, a person does not have the right to be rude to you but oftentimes rudeness is met with rudeness as a part of the human condition. Good luck.

Comment: Please keep our [Be Nice](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy in mind everyone when interacting with others and let's avoid escalating a misunderstanding into an argument.

Comment: @Fatima I'm not singling anyone out here or judging this answer, just asking both of you to remain kind. It's better to disengage from a post if comments become unproductive as was the case here.